# Call mode-specific backspace from "smart-backspace" function

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode

I'm writing an IntelliJ-style "smart backspace" function which does the following:

- If the whole of the line up to the point is whitespace

  - Join the line to the previous line, killing that whitespace
  - Indent the line
- Otherwise, just delete a char **as normal**

I've got the smart backspace working, but the **as normal** part is proving difficult.

```lisp
(defun smart-backspace ()
  (interactive)
  (if (beginning-of-line-text-p)
      (progn (join-line)
             (indent-according-to-mode))
      (delete-backward-char 1)))
```

The problem is most language modes provide their own version of `delete-backward-char`, so overriding backspace like this doesn't do handy (or crucial!) stuff such as `paredit`/`smartparens`' `sp-backward-delete-char`, which keeps the sexp tree intact when you backspace over a closing delimiter.

What I'm asking is: is there a way to call the "default" binding for a key or mode from inside a function such as mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes".  As usual, I suspect that's not the answer you were looking for, tho.

How to do that depends on how you bind your backspace key to your `smart-backspace` command.  One way to do it is to bind it as part of a minor mode:

```
(defvar smart-backspace-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "DEL") 'smart-backspace)
    map))

(define-minor-mode smart-backspace-mode
  "Be smart."
  :global t)
```

in which case you can call the "default" binding with something like:

```
(let ((smart-backspace-mode nil))
  (command-execute (key-binding (this-single-command-keys))))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! It needed a couple of tweaks - first it's `command-execute` not `execute-command`, and I needed to add a fallback to `delete-backwards-char` when `key-binding` doesn't return anything - but otherwise this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Stefan's solution is almost perfect, but it required the following modifications:

- Use `command-execute` instead of `execute-command`
- Provide a fallback to backspace when no key binding is defined, via `or`:

```lisp
(defun smart-backspace ()
  (interactive)
  (if (beginning-of-line-text-p)
      (progn
        (join-line)
        (indent-according-to-mode))
      (let ((smart-backspace-mode nil))
        (command-execute (or
                          (key-binding (this-single-command-keys))
                          'evil-delete-backward-char-and-join)))))
```